# systemd-timesyncd: fails on boot due to ordering cycle (dbus, sysinit)

Tags: linux, boot, time, ntp

i've been having a hard time with a pretty basic Rocky Linux 9 setup where my
systemd-timesyncd unit consistently fails on boot.

here are the logs

```
Feb 12 18:22:17 bigpu systemd[1]: sysinit.target: Found ordering cycle on systemd-timesyncd.service/start
Feb 12 18:22:17 bigpu systemd[1]: sysinit.target: Found dependency on dbus.socket/start
Feb 12 18:22:17 bigpu systemd[1]: sysinit.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
Feb 12 18:22:17 bigpu systemd[1]: sysinit.target: Job systemd-timesyncd.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
```

i did not change the unit definitions of either systemd-timesyncd, dbus
nor sysinit. no idea what's happening.

googling did not help. any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of a strange bug in Rocky 9. I am not sure if it exists in original RHEL 9 or in other RHEL clones.
The main reason consists of the line

```
After=systemd-sysusers.service dbus.socket
```

in the file "*/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service*".

Systemd-timesyncd wants to be executed after "dbus.socket" starts, which depends on "sysinit.target". And the latter depends on "systemd-timesyncd". So, the circle is closed.

One needs to remove "dbus.socket" to resolve the issue, but "*systemctl edit systemd-timesyncd*" would not help. Because there is an alias of this unit named "*dbus-org.freedesktop.timesync1.service*" which will not be affected by systemd overrides.

Thus, you need to edit the file "*/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service*" manually removing all mentions about "dbus.socket" from it. Then run "systemctl daemon-reload" to apply the changes.

Please note, that system upgrade may cause rollback of the systemd config files to their defaults. So please keep in mind this possible drawback.